# PayPal API DoDirectPayment required IP field does not support IPv6

Tags: paypal

DoDirectPayment API call requires an IP address field (this is a buyer's IP) so I am using ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr to get the request IP. However this IP is assumed to be IPv4 and
does not seem to support IPv6. Have anyone found a workaround for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP Address is not required by PayPal, so I do not send IP address in local debug mode. I only send in production mode in which we use IPv4.

```
DoDirectPaymentRequestDetailsType details = new DoDirectPaymentRequestDetailsType();
#if (!DEBUG)
details.IPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
#endif
```

Comment: Please tale a look at: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoDirectPayment IP address is a required field. You don't see a validation error if you don't include them?

Comment: I use SOAP API; it works for me without IP Address. Did you try aleady?

Comment: I'm using nvp, it seems to work in the sandbox  without the IP address.... PayPal should indicate in the docs the field is recommended but not required if they don't plan to support all the protocols at least.... Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

`IPADDRESS` is an optional (but recommended) field at the moment.
Support for IPv6 is being added, but is not yet available.
As the [API document](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoDirectPayment) indicates, the `IPADDRESS` field is recorded as a means to detect possible fraud.